# Making deb file

Tags: debian, package, deb

I want to make deb file with java project I made and install it on other computer
I checked Debian New Maintainer's Guide and other tutorials, still I can't get it.

I made a file 'MyApp' and made a .deb file with it,

> MyApp/Debian/control
>   MyApp/MyApp.jar

And installed it in my terminal to check it

> sudo dpkg -i MyApp.deb

The terminal says it is unpacked, but nothing happens

So here are my questions,

1. How do I execute 'MyApp' in terminal simply typing

   > MyApp

in my terminal?

2. How do I make man page with it? I want to install man page with MyApp.deb. I made MyApp.1 file but I don't know where to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packaging (for Debian, or anything else), is non-trivial.
It's not something that can be explained in a forum in three paragraphs.

Luckily, there is quite a bit of documentation available for [creating Debian packages](https://www.debian.org/doc/devel-manuals), e.g.

- [Guide for Debian Maintainers](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debmake-doc/index.en.html), as found in the [debmake-doc](https://packages.debian.org/debmake-doc) package.
- [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/index.en.html) as found in the [maint-guide](https://packages.debian.org/maint-guide) package
- [Introduction to Debian packaging](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/packaging-tutorial/packaging-tutorial.en.pdf), as found in the [packaging-tutorial](https://packages.debian.org/packaging-tutorial) package.

Your problems *are* covered by these tutorials (even though the list includes the "New Maintainer Guide" which you've already read).

To give a more specific advice:

- make sure you know where your stuff should be installed to. if your project has a `make install` use that. if it doesn't, what would it do if there was one?
- a `.jar` file is not an executable. if you want your program to be executable, you will need a wrapper script, that calls your `.jar` file with the proper java-interpreter
- checkout packages that do something similar; learn from them
- checkout the `debian/install` file
- checkout the `debian/manpages` file

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Debian doc contain very complicated methods to create deb file. 
You can find simple steps to follow to create deb files in below link
https://www.lookup2learn.com/post/how-to-create-debian-package